# Is there any benefits of creating and using selectors outside of NgRx reducers?

Tags: angular, ngrx

My team is using NgRx for a while now and often they are using createSelector function to listen to store changes in container components or services. From different NgRx example apps, I've never seen that. Is there any performance/maintainability benefits doing that?

If it's the case, how should I structure that?

Comment: You would normally use selectors from components. Where other than what do you see listeners exist?

Comment: Selectors should be used in Angular injectable entities which are components and services mainly. You can't really use it in reducers.

Comment: yes, you're right sorry. I was confused because all selectors were inside the reducers folder like on the NgRx example-app https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/projects/example-app/src/app/auth/reducers/index.ts

Comment: I think my question was more, should we create selectors inside one specific file per state slice instead of creating them in the components directly or it depends?